# urllib.urlretrieve creates file on disk

Tags: python-2.7, urllib

I do this:

```
thing = urllib.urlretrieve(url, "somefile.jpg")
```

It works, it gets the file, but it actually creates a file on the file system in the cwd. I write the file a little later to an appropriate path, but I don't want the file in the cwd at that time. What can I do?

Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the file to go in a different directory, simply specify a path to where you want the file to go.

If you don't want the file to still be in the cwd after copying it, then delete the copy you don't want.

If you don't want to create a file at all, use something like `urlopen`.

Comment: `urlopen` is the thing.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple solutions 1. Change the cwd or 2. specify an alternate directory (as suggested by Scott Hunter), to do these:

**1. Change your cwd** (current working directory):

`os.chdir("/Users/Desktop/SpecificDirectory/")`
-now try your script.

OR

**2. Specify an alternate directory** in the download urllib command:

```
`thing = urllib.urlretrieve(url,"/Users/Desktop/SpecificDirectory/somefile.jpg")`
```